# How to select one hour each day from hourly data in R?

Tags: r

I have a table that can be read as:

```
data=read.table("C:\\users\\product0101.txt",sep="", header  = TRUE, row.names=NULL)
```

The table looks like:

```
    which is hourly data for three years so 24 values for each day.
```

to plot 
we simply do:

```
     plot(data$sm, data$date,col='red')
```

but I want to extract (for later use) and plot only  values which correspond to 04:00 each day. any help please

```
    dput(head(data))
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("2006/01/01", 
    "2006/01/02", "2006/01/03", "2006/01/04", "2006/01/05", "2006/01/06", 
    "2006/01/07", "2006/01/08", "2006/01/09", "2006/01/10", "2006/01/11", 
    "2006/01/12", "2006/01/13", "2006/01/14", "2006/01/15", "2006/01/16", 
    "2006/01/17", "2006/01/18", "2006/01/19", "2006/01/20", "2006/01/21", 
    "2006/01/22", "2006/01/23", "2006/01/24", "2006/01/25", "2006/01/26",
```

Comment: Can you please add the output from `dput(head(data))`?

Comment: Can you not simply create a new dataset `data4 <- subset(data, time=="04:00")` and use that for your plot?

Comment: @GavinKelly's answer probably is the way to go. If not, please edit the question, your `dput` output is incomplete. I would suggest first recoding your `Date` column using `as.Date(as.character(data$Date))`. Right now, this column is a factor, which will not be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second edit:

```
data$Date <- as.Date(as.character(data$Date), "%y/%m/%d")
plot(data$sm[data$time=="04:00"], data$Date[data$time=="04:00"], col='red')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
plot(data$sm[data$time=="04:00",], data$date, col='red')
```